# How to compare 2 string variables

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please tell me how to compare 2 string variables 
I'm not talking about a string variable and a string (that is already posted on this site)

I have tried this:

```
if (s isEqualToString: str) {
  // ...
}
```

Here s and ss are two NSMutableStrings that already having values, but this isn't working.  I have also tried isEqual but failed again.

Please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing brackets.

```
if ([s isEqualToString:ss]) {
    // ...
}
```

You can't just use `==`, because a string with the same content may be stored in different objects.